# Maven setting prefix of self-made plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

today i tried something with making own plugins for maven.
It worked great ;)
After that i wated to set a prefix to use the maven comman in 
a shorter way. This worked great too ;)

My problem now is:

If i want to use my prefix, i have to set the groupId of my plugin
in the .m2/settings.xml. Otherwise he isnt able to find the plugin (ofcourse not)

I want to know now: how is it possible to do this automatically?
I dont want the person who wants to use my plugin to set the groupId manually.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin prefix has nothing to do with if a plugin can be found or not. If you haven't define a pluginGroup or a fit into the naming conventions you have to type the full qualified name incl. package, version of your plugin like:

```
mvn package:yourpluginname-maven-plugin:1.0.1:WhatEverGoal
```

To use a short command line you have to follow [naming conventions like](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html):

```
yourpluginname-maven-plugin
```

or

```
maven-yourpluginmame-plugin
```

The conventions maven-yourpluginname-plugin is reserved for plugins which are coming from Apache org...so the best thing is to name your plugin like:

```
yourpluginname-maven-plugin
```

Comment: yeah but actually this isnt working!
My plugin: maven-test-plugin
So i try to call it with mvn my.groupId:test:myGoal
but it isnt working